# Signalr doesn't connect to hubs on firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

I have a basic MVC application which is integrated with signal R. I'm tracking online users using this application.

Following is my Hub class

public class UserHub : Hub
{
    static long counter = 0;

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    //Update Count when User is connected
    counter = counter+1;
    Clients.All.UpdateCount(counter);
    return base.OnConnected();
}

public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
{

    counter = counter-1;
    Clients.All.UpdateCount(counter);
    return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);

}
```

}

Following is my javascript code

```
        $.connection.hub.logging = true;
        //setup hubs
        var userHub = $.connection.userHub;
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

        });

        //function to recieve data from server
        userHub.client.UpdateCount = function (count) {
            $('#counter').text(count);
        }
```

I have registered the in startup.cs class as well.

The problem is signalr Is throwing an error "SignalR: No hubs have been subscribed to.  " When I refresh the page like 5 times, then the signal r is connected to hub and data is getting pulled.

Did anyone face this issue?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start the connection after you're subscribing to the client method, like so:

```
var cHub = $.connection.userHub;
cHub.client.UpdateCount = function (count) {
    $('#counter').text(count);
}

$.connection.hub.start();
```

Comment: I tried this, this happens to work. Can you tell me the reason behind it ?

Comment: Take a look in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064651/the-on-event-on-the-signalr-client-hub-does-not-get-called  basically, signalR subscribe to the hub client callbacks on start so you have to define it before.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by setting a timeout. Following is my code.

```
var cHub = $.connection.userHub;
            setTimeout(function () {
                $.connection.hub.start();
            },
                1000);
            //function to recieve data from server
            cHub.client.UpdateCount = function (count) {
                $('#counter').text(count);
            }

            $.connection.hub.logging = true;
```

I still was not able to figure out why the firefox is doing that.